# How can I get the 'discription' from 'articles'

Tags: python, json

[image]

I would like to get the 'description' from 'articles'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response['articles'][<integer index>]['description']`, where `<integer index>` gives the index of the article that you want to access.